# Autofill data from one tab to another under certain criteria

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, autofill, auto-populate

I enter customer details onto an excel 2010 spreadsheet, ie customer name, date, description of order, amount of order etc. Sometimes, under certain criteria, the same or part of the same information needs to be added to another tab, ie tab2, on the same spreadsheet. I wanted to create an automated system to populate tab2, but cant figure out how.

I thought about creating another column in tab1, before all the customer information, which had a dropdown list option for yes/no when asked the question 'does it fit the criteria to add customer information to tab2'. This column would act as an alert, so that if i selected 'yes', then any customer information i enter in tab1 would then populate into tab2. But I dont know how to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Without more detailed information I can't offer specific code advise.  But in general you can use VBA `Worksheet_Change` event to detect new data entered into sheet 1 (tab 1) and test if it meets some criteria.  If it does, execute some code to copy to sheet 2